# DBF to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, dbf

Есть ли какой-нибудь простой пусть, чтобы создать структуру dbf файла на ms sql сервере. То есть данные в принципе не нужны. Нужна только структура самой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, собственно есть такой инструмент. В Management studio есть мастер импорта-экспорта.